# how to kill all process of aws unsing linux command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, service, process, kill

my EC2 system has got 100 % CPU utilization.So I need to find which commands are running in the background. So that I can kill all the running services of AWS. What is the Linux command for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `htop` commands to find the status of the server. You can either use `kill -9 <process_id>`.
Or , to kill all aws services runnnig, use :

```
pgrep aws 
pkill
```

Comment: of course, i was having more than 5 minutes to find this on google and later to share this here :happy